# Group velocity dispersion for coupled waveguides

Tags: electromagnetism, waveguide

I am an EE undergrad currently studying group velocity dispersion (GVD) for coupled waveguides, and am quite confused on the following question: how do you characterize group velocity dispersion for a coupled waveguide system, like a conventional symmetric directional coupler? I can certainly get the dispersion relation ($\beta-\omega$ relation) for the individual waveguides, be them planar, rectangular and so on as they are almost always treated in an integrated optics or photonics textbook, but how do you characterize GVD for the coupled system, and is there a general treatment for it? Any help or even suggestion on references is appreciated!

Comment: (1) feed the coupler from port 0; (2) terminate ports 1, 2 and 3 with matched loads; (3) measure the phases at the loads as you vary the frequency $\omega$. That function is the dispersion relationship and it is non-trivially related to the waveguide's dispersion because the coupling between the lines is frequency dependent.

Comment: @hyportnex Thank you for the comment. Yes, I know experimentally how it should be done in general. What I am interested in is how to mathematically characterize the GVD for the overall system (e.g. do I come up with a "coupled propagation constant"?)